# In Flutter how do I make the whole page be a vertical list but an element inside it is a horizontal list?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 return Expanded(
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('data'),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]

As seen in the image, there are 4 options above and I can move them horizontally. But I want to add a few card representations just below it and I want them to move horizontally as well. But I want to make the page-wide scrollable vertically up and down. But I am getting viewport error.

Answer (score 0):

We should use `Expanded` widget in **flex** widgets such as `Row` or `Column` or `Flex`.

if you know the **height** of the inner `ListView` then replace the `Expanded` for inner `ListView` with `SizedBox` widget and set **height** to it.

you don't need root `Expanded` widget too, if you are not having any of the **flex** widgets as its parent widget.